# To trash an estate or to curse my opponents?

Tags: dominion

I'm playing Dominion, 3-player game, I get a 5-2 split on the opening and get a Witch and a Pearl Diver. Other players have 4-3, they both open Jack of All Trades and Silver. I pick up a Jack and Silver my second time through, and my Witch shows up at the very bottom, so I draw it on turn 5 with the hand:

```
Witch, Jack of All Trades, Estate, Copper, Copper.
```

The question: which one do I play? It's still very early in the game, no one else has a Witch at this point, is it better to try to slow my opponents down by cursing them or to speed my own deck up by gaining a silver and trashing an estate?

Of course, as in all Dominion strategy questions, this could depend on the other Kingdom cards, but I'd like to keep answers general. That said, in case you're curious I'll provide context for this game because I don't think any of the other cards impacted my decision much: there weren't many other tempting kingdom cards.

```
$6: Harem, Fairgrounds
$5: Witch, Horn of Plenty
$4: Bureaucrat, Gardens, Jack of All Trades, Smithy
$3: Smugglers
$2: Pearl Diver
```

The only other $5 was Horn of Plenty--which I definitely don't want to pick up too early. My general strategy was to get either a Smithy or a second Jack depending on whether my opponents picked up Witches, and otherwise buy money and Provinces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should play Jack of All Trades**

You will not be slowing your opponents down much with Witch, because they are buying Jack of All Trades as well, and will just [trash the curse](http://dominionstrategy.com/2011/12/05/hinterlands-jack-of-all-trades/) you give them.

> DoubleJack/Big Money crushes attacks.  Sea Hag?  Trash the Curse.  Militia?  Draw back up.  Rabble?  Chuck the Victory card.  And all throughout it’s gaining Silver.  Attacks barely matter at all to DoubleJack: in the simulators, it obliterates Sea Hag/Big Money and DoubleMilitia, solidly beats ChapelWitch and ChapelMountebank, and goes toe-to-toe with DoubleMountebank and DoubleWitch.